# How can I fix this foreach to let the link work for every element/pages?

Tags: php

I'm quite new to php an d I need some help. 
I have a list of pages which I access to through different divs showing the titles of the argument. I put a foreach to cycle all the links. How can I get to the relative pages through a link? Put that my a href that remain after write the foreach is only one.

This is the element I want to cycle and I went like this

```
foreach ($prog as $progs) :
/*this is the a href that lasts*/
a href="angular.html";
echo $progs['img'];
echo $progs['title'];
echo $progs['description'];
endforeach;
```

I would to go to the right argument page through the div links. But now they all bring to that href. Thank you for your help and time dedicated to this!

Comment: At least to me it's not clear how you want to use the 'output'/'result' of this foreach and what it should be as a consequence. To you want to build several strings like "angular.html/imagename","angular.html/theTitle", .. ?

Comment: I explain..I have 20 divs which host a link to the related page, like angular, node and so on. I put this foreach for every div as to show few rows of code. Can I go to the other links using only this foreach? Because as for now, obviously, the link which lasts is only that I told you. And if I click to a div different from "angular", I'm going still to this page ad not, for example, to the php page

Comment: It's not clear that this code even outputs valid HTML?? But assuming it did, you're hard-coding "angular.html" into the href, so of course all links that you create will point to that same page. Have you got some field in $progs which contains the name of a different HTML page that you want to link to instead? It's not very clear. Perhaps you need someone to help you translate your question better, because it's hard to understand what you mean.